# How to get device width and height in Ionic using TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to get device width and height in ionic 2 using typescript.

In previous version of ionic 2 I used,

```
window.screen.width
window.screen.height
```

but in newer version this is not working.

How it is work with Type Script + ionic 2?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use the Platform information for this.

Internally the `platform` uses the `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` but

> Using this method is preferred since the dimension is a cached value,
> which reduces the chance of multiple and expensive DOM reads.

### Ionic 4/5

**Docs**: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform#width-number

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({...})
export MyApp {
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log('Width: ' + platform.width());
      console.log('Height: ' + platform.height());
    });
  }
}
```

### Ionic 2/3

**Docs**: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/platform/Platform/#width

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyApp {
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      console.log('Width: ' + platform.width());
      console.log('Height: ' + platform.height());
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it goes by the standards of ionic 2

Comment: In case you are using ionic 4+ change the import statement from `import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';` to `import {Platform} from '@ionic/angular';`

Comment: @DavidAddoteye Agreed!

Answer (score 8):

Try using window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth to get height and width of the device respectively.

Comment: This will trigger a DOM repaint, which is expensive. See the other answer instead.